# Exclude a subdirectory in pep8's setup.cfg

Tags: python, pep8

I want to exclude my project's `catkin/devel/` directory from pep8.

Things I tried that *DIDN'T* work:

```
exclude = catkin/devel/
exclude = /catkin/devel/
```

One thing I found that *sort of* worked:

```
exclude = devel/
```

*However, this ignores **all** sub-directories named `devel/`... including `catkin/devel/` but also `catkin/foo/devel/` etc. (which may have some python that needs a peppin).*

How do I exclude a specific directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a <kbd>.</kbd> before the full path:

```
exclude = ./catkin/devel/
```